# Is there a way to get stats about fees paid (highest, lowest, average) in a specific block?

Tags: transaction-fees, block

I'd prefer to get the stats from my full node via bitcoin-cli, but if that's not possible some API would do the job too...

Comment: It is possible using bitcoin-cli, but you’ll have to write some scripts that calculate and index each transaction’s fee rate